# JQUERY Success return

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jQuery UI box that passes data onto my servlet, if the servlet fails the request, i have this set;

```
             response.setContentType("text/xml");
             response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
             response.getWriter().write("<valid>false</valid>");
```

How can I access this from the success function? (or is that wrong?)

Here is my jQuery code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        //this is the servlet file that processes the data and send mail
                        url: "Register",

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "POST",

                        //pass the data        
                        data: data,    

                        //Do not cache the page
                        cache: false,

                        //success
                        success: function (response) {             
                            //$( "#message" ).append( response );



                        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context here? I assume this `success` callback is part of an AJAX request??

Comment: I have added my full code, im making a register box, it currently works, but im unsure how to add a alert for the user to say if it was a success or not.

Comment: what about your jQuery where you make the request to the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the content of the XML response.

```
success: function (responseXml) {
    if ($(responeXml).text() == 'false') {
        $('#message').text("Failed");
    } else {
        $('#message').text("Succeed");
    }
}
```

I'd however prefer JSON over XML, it's easier and more intuitive to traverse it in jQuery.

Comment: am i sending the response back in the right way, as nothing seems to happen?

Comment: Debug the code. What lines in JS and Java got executed and what not? What does the `$(responseXml)` actually contain? Etc.